# Android variable creating issue when sudo meteor run android-device perform

Tags: android, linux, cordova, meteor

> export ANDROID_HOME=/home/haiderali/android-sdk-linux
>
> export PATH=${PATH}:/home/haiderali/android-sdk-linux/tools
>
> export PATH=${PATH}:/home/haiderali/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

i added this on bashrc file and run this command "sudo meteor run android-device" it's give me environment error but I successfully installed all the tools required for meteor android build.

> Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build
>   apps for Android.
>                                                  Please follow the installation instructions here:
>   https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux
>                                                  Status of the requirements:
>    ✓ Java JDK
>
> ✗ Android SDK: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try
>   setting setting it manually.
>
> Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your
>   'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
>
> ✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. >If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment >variable.
>
> ✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Could not >find Android SDK directory. Might need to install Android SDK or set up >'ANDROID_HOME' envvariable.

Please Somebody help. :(

Comment: Try the solution here and see if that works for you http://superuser.com/questions/816369/cordova-android-install-on-linux

Comment: @PhilipPryde i saw it before and tried it too. but nothing happened . i'm trying last 2 days. it's really really wired. :( :'(

Comment: Try `sudo -E meteor run android-device` Here the `-E` preserves the environment. I think the bash is working off a separate PATH to sudo which has its own PATH this command should confirm that